# Create a new child table when a row is added to parent table

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm using c# and access database for a document management system.

So far I have created two tables:

1. Project Table: 
   In this table there are few columns sucha as "ProjectCode", "ProjectManager", "ProjectName",... (ProjectCode is unique)
2. Records:
   This table is to hold the records for each project such as "Document No.", "Revision", "Title", "DateReceived", ...

My Question is:
Is it possible to create a separate "Records" table for each project whenever I add a new project to "Project Table"

ex: If I add new ProjectCode "A0002" then new Record table will be created as "RecordsA0002"

Comment: You could also add a foreign key to your Records table, pointing to the Project table. That's far easier to work with than lots of project-specific tables.

Comment: You could and should! Creating different tables with same data-structure is worst case violating database normalization. If you need data from one project only create a query that filters on the foreign key (ProjectID).

Comment: Hans, BitAccesser, I got your point. appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Only for demonstration purposes, no error checks:
            // This code will only work as long as the table "Records002" does not exist
            string id = "002";
            // First create an new database if necessary
            Catalog cat = OpenDatabase();

            // Create a new table "Records" using ADOX ...
            Table table = new Table();
            table.Name = "Records" + id;
            cat.Tables.Append(table);

            // Add Column "RecordsID" with Autoincrement
            ADOX.Column col = new Column();
            col.Name = "RecordsID";
            col.ParentCatalog = cat;
            col.Type = ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger;
            col.Properties["Nullable"].Value = false;
            col.Properties["AutoIncrement"].Value = true;
            table.Columns.Append(col);



            // Make "Records" the primary key
            ADOX.Index index = new ADOX.Index();
            index.PrimaryKey = true;
            index.Name = "PK_RecordsID";
            index.Columns.Append("RecordsID", table.Columns["RecordsID"].Type, table.Columns["RecordsID"].DefinedSize);
            table.Indexes.Append(index);

            MessageBox.Show("A new Data Table is successfully Created");
```

Comment: Don't do that! See my comment on question.

Comment: _// Only for demonstration purposes_  ... Indeed!